# What is the difference between CONCAT vs CONCAT_WS in SQL

Tags: sql, concatenation, concat-ws

Please clarify what information is pulled and how it is reorganized using CONCAT vs CONCAT_WS in SQL. See example below for more details.

For example,

CONCAT('Google', '.com') creates Google.com

but I don't understand how

CONCAT_WS ('.', 'www', 'google', 'com') also create Google .com

To me it seems like it would create .wwwgooglecom

Why is this not the case?

For example,

CONCAT('Google', '.com') creates Google.com

but I don't understand how

CONCAT_WS ('.', 'www', 'google', 'com') also create Google .com

To me it seems like it would create .wwwgooglecom

Why is this not the case?

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

`CONCAT` just combines the values provided as arguments as it is. For example - `CONCAT('www','.google','.com')` produces `www.google.com`

`CONCAT_WS` will combine the provided values based on the separator, which is the first argument. For example -
`CONCAT_WS('.', 'www','google','com')` will produce `www.google.com`.

Comment: You could tell OP and the rest of the readers which dbms this is for.

Comment: It was mentioned in the question that it is about SQL. This holds true for MySQL and PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

`CONCAT_WS` will handle `NULL` values as empty strings, whereas `CONCAT` will return NULL.